# ¿Como personalizo el Email Layout de FirebaseUI?

Tags: android, firebase, material-design, firebase-auth

Tengo un proyecto que presentar y es una aplicación de Android.
Estoy creando una aplicación con Firebase y estoy probando FirebaseUI y quiero personalizar el layout del Email.

[image: Login FirebaseUI]

El layout del login de FirebaseUI no me importa, pero quiero cambiar el layout del correo.
[image: FirebaseUI Email]

Debido a que quiero personalizar este layout y el que lleva en la interfaz de FirebaseUI se ve mal con el tema oscuro y voy aplicar **Material Theming (Material Design)** personalizado.
¿Como puedo personalizar este layout del correo?
Solo he visto en la documentación que solo se puede personalizar el layout del login, pero no el layout del email.

Answer (score 0):

Nop, no se puede. Cuando mucho, puedes cambiar de color lo que ves en pantalla, pero solo eso. No puedes reordenar los componentes

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn revisa [answer] para realizar respuestas en el sitio.